# Issue with switch case in Recyclerview as it opens wrong activity when items are filtered

Tags: android

I have used a switch case in a `RecyclerView` to open different `Activity`s. It works perfectly when items are not filtered. But when the items are filtered, items show wrong `Activity`s. I think it happens because when items are filtered they get upper position. I don't know how to come over this issue.

```
public void onItemClick(int position)  {
    switch (position ){
        case 0:
            Intent pope = new Intent(this, Pope.class);
            startActivity(pope);
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent austin = new Intent(this, AlfredAustine.class);
            startActivity(austin);
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent housman = new Intent(this, AlfredHousman.class);
            startActivity(housman);
            break;
        case 3:
            Intent tennyson = new Intent(this, LordTennyson.class);
            startActivity(tennyson);
            break;
        case 4:
            Intent swinburn = new Intent(this, AlgernonSwinburn.class);
            startActivity(swinburn);
            break;
        case 5:
            Intent lang = new Intent(this, AndrewLang.class);
            startActivity(lang);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, its hard to tell exactly what's going wrong with the code you have shared. Consider adding more relevant code such as your bind method and the attachment of the click listener. It just looks like a normal switch case otherwise

Comment: I beelive that you are using the position of the item in the viewer list. I you filter the position of the items are updating according to the filter. Do you need use a fixed value for each item and pass it to function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a switch case on the item position. This can lead to problems when your adapter is modified. When you 'filter' your adapter (however you are implementing it), positions of the items can change and this will lead to your switch case not working as expected.

Consider using switch case on an item's parameter or if you must use position, store the position in your item object instead of relying on the adapter position.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a software design issue question. This is the way I would solve that. In the Adapter probably you have a list of models. Something like this:

```
List<MyModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
```

So in MyModel class you should define an id for the model. E.e:

```
public class MyModel {
  @NonNull
  private int id;
  ....
}
```

Then the switch will be something like:

```
public void onItemClick(int position)  {
  
    switch (models.get(position).getId()){
        case POPE_ID:
            Intent pope = new Intent(this, Pope.class);
            startActivity(pope);
            break;
        case ALFRED_ID:
            Intent austin = new Intent(this, AlfredAustine.class);
            startActivity(austin);
            break;
        case ALFRED_HOUSMAN_ID:
            Intent housman = new Intent(this, AlfredHousman.class);
            startActivity(housman);
            break;
        .....
    }
}
```